# unable to update listitem external data column sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I try update Extenal data column but it doesn't work, new value is not stored. (new value is visible on details form but not on list, rehreshing external data type does not return related external column values)

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("site.com"))
{
    using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb("site.com"))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = oSiteCollection.RootWeb)
        {
            SPList docLib = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["list name"];

            SPListItemCollection items = docLib.Items;
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                //item["n"] is external column data field 

                item["n"] = item["notice"].ToString();
                item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check using `item.Update()` insted of `item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()`

Comment: i did't know why did you gave using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb("site.com"))...Check by removing that line once

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the field type and is quite complicated to get right.
There is a free external data field migration/copy tool here:
http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com/2013/06/bcs-bdc-external-data-lookup-field.html

I included source code and links to relevant articles.